# Gtk how to add label item child

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

As a way how to learn Gtk and python I decided to re-write program which GUI was build in Glade (Gtk 2). I need a little push now, as I don't know how to make Hbox  child item of Label ? Or maybe I just misunderstood it ? Here's how it looks in Glade:

[image: Glade treeview]

how to add Hbox into this piece of code ? :

```
    table1.attach(frame, 0, 2, 0, 1, gtk.FILL, gtk.FILL)
    notebook1.append_page(table1, label1)

    align = gtk.Alignment(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
    frame.add(align)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really create the structure shown in the Glade screenshot: You can only add one child to a GtkFrame. I believe Glade is mistakenly showing you an internal child of the frame (the GtkAlignment that the frame itself uses to layout the possible frame label).

Don't add the GtkAlignment at all (use the GtkFrame API instead if you need to set the frame label alignment). Just create an HBox and add it into the Frame, then create a Label and pack it into the HBox.